# Not able to identify the element in dropdown

Tags: java, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSZqp.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiBbU.png)I have a [drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnPuO.png), and click will display the list of branches.

I am able to identify the drop down(arrow inverted in ui) and  click on it, by using below code.

```
//click on the drop down
@FindBy(xpath ="//[@id=\"miniTable\"]/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/div/div/div[1]")
WebElement selectbranch;
```

Note that ,There is no select tag for the drop down

**Issue:**

I am able to identify the drop down and click on that, But I am not able to get one of the branch from the drop down.

Comment: Can you please share the html of the dropdown item.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Drop down has not made of `Select` tag, `Select` class from **selenium** will not work.

As you have mentioned that you are able to click on drop down, you can use this code after that :

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(by.xpath(" your locator"));
for(WebElement element : options){
 if(element.getText().equals(" the value you want to select from drop down")){
    element.click();
}
}
```

in place of `your locator` , you'd have to give a common locator for all the elements of drop down.

Let me know if you have any more concerns.

Comment: my concern is, when a click on the drop down, i can't see the list of branches in the html tag, only when i click on any branch manually,i could see the branch name in the html code

Comment: @saidayapule : So, write the locator that should be common for all the option, You don't really have a choice here since select tag is not present in HTML

Comment: yes to write a locator common to all the options, i should be able to idenitfy, but, when i click on the drop down(right click, inspect element), i am able to find locator for the drop down, but no locator for the list of branches, please see the images attached